# Error trying to implement type checking with SFINAE

Tags: c++, sfinae, type-traits

I was following Jean Guegant's SFINAE blog post, where he implements a type trait using **sizeof()** which checks if there is a **serialize** function in the class. Inside which he has this **reallyHas** struct which checks if serialize is just a member of the class or an actual member function, by doing this

```
template<typename T>
struct has_serialize {
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];

    template<typename U, U u> struct reallyHas{}; 

    template <typename C>
    static yes& test(reallyHas<string (C::*)(), &C::serialize>*){}

    // for const method
    template<typename C>
    static yes& test(reallyHas<string (C::*)() const, &C::serialize>*){}

    template<typename> // variadic template
    static no& test(...){} // sink hole

    enum {
         value = (sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes))
    };
};
```

This works fine only when the test function has the signature of

```
template <typename C>
static yes& test(reallyHas<string (C::*)(), &C::serialize>*){}
```

But not when

```
template <typename C>
static yes& test(reallyHas<string (C::*)(), &C::serialize>){}
```

I don't really understand the significance of the * in the argument, In the end we are just checking if the substitution happens or not, so shouldn't it work in both the cases

Comment: The literal `0` in `test<T>(0)` is convertable into a `T*`, but not into `T`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplifying, the principle of SFINAE is to provide a few candidates for a symbol (overloads, template specializations etc.). Then, for a given argument the compiler will try out every candidate one at a time, until it finds the best match.

In this case, the `test` function is used for SFINAE. The goal is to have it defined in such a way that for types with a `serialize` member function it will resolve to a function `test` that returns a `yes` type and for a function returning the `no` type otherwise.

The example shown above accomplishes this by using a trick where `0` gets converted to a pointer. It is possible for such a conversion to occur by the rules of the language.

When `test<T>(0)` gets called, the compiler will first look at the first overload and by substituting `T` will end up with a function that looks something like this:

```cpp
static yes& test(reallyHas<string (T::*)(), &T::serialize>*){}
```

The compiler will now see if this overload can be chosen. It will see if `0` (`int`) can be converted to `reallyHas<string (T::*)(), &T::serialize>*`. As `int`s can be converted to pointers an error will occur only if the type `reallyHas<string (T::*)(), &T::serialize>*` would be ill-formed. This is the case if `T` doesn't have an appropriate a member function `&T::serialize` that can be converted to the function pointer `string (T::*)()`. For example for `using T = int`, it would fail as `int` isn't even a class type.

If the substitution fails, the compiler will analogically try the second overload and finally the third one. As the third one is declared as `static no& test(...){}` it can accept any arguments. In this case it could just as well be declared as `static no& test(unsigned){}` as `0` is convertible to `unsigned`.

Now notice what happens if you would change the first overload to this:

```cpp
template <typename C>
static yes& test(reallyHas<string (C::*)(), &C::serialize>){}
```

Now the substitution failure will happen always (even if `T` has a member `serialize` function) as `0` (`int`) is not convertible to a class type `reallyHas<T>`.

Comment: Ahh got it. So ig if I did test<T>(reallyHas{}) it would have worked in the second case. Thanks!

Comment: @Bad_Panda It wouldn't work as each template instantiation is a distinct type. There exists no such type as `reallyHas`. `reallyHas` is a template that only "turns into" a type when provided template parameters.

Comment: Yeah my bad! So it has to be done only like this.